# Add share button in magiczoomplus

Tags: javascript, css, magiczoomplus

> I am creating a WordPress site using Artisteer and various plugins to show off some photo galleries. I have also purchased a e-commerce WordPress theme that I have included as a subdirectory. In this theme they have a share button that I like the functionality of. I want to replicate the button in the front section of the site within the gallery pages. See the attached links to see what I am talking about.
>
> http://rrestricted.com/eshop/20mens/jay-chillin
>   http://rrestricted.com/gallery/jay-3
>
> The first link has the share button (loveheart icon) and the second the gallery that I want to add the button to. If you click on the images in the gallery you will see a large lightbox come up. I want to add the Share button just above the navigation buttons.

This is my require from a customer.

I was searched magiczoomplus.js, but I can't add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like they want to add a share button to the gallery page you link to. What does that have to do with magiczoomplus? Magiczoom is used when you mouse of an image it gives you a zoomed-in close up of it. The share button just creates a lightbox widget when you click on it.

EDIT:

Based on your comment I think I understand. Don't put the heart icon in the zoomed photo. Put it somewhere else on the page hidden. Then when the zoomed image appears, move the heart icon into place next to the navigation icons. You can base its position on the coordinates of the nav icons. Then make sure its z-index is high enough.

Comment: Hi @david. My customer want "The first link has the share button (loveheart icon) and the second the gallery that **I want to add the button to**. **If you click on the images in the gallery you will see a large lightbox come up. I want to add the Share button just above the navigation buttons.**". I was added a share button in 1 zoomed photo in gallery by jquery, but it don't working.